# Determine whether each of the functions $2^{n+1}$ and $2^{2n}$ is $O(2^n)$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, asymptotics

Determine whether each of the functions $2^{n+1}$ and $2^{2n}$ is $O(2^n)$.

Since $2^n$ < $2^{n+1}$, you can say $2^{n+1}$ is  not $O(2^{n})$

Since $2^n$ is < $2^{2n}$, you can say  $2^{2n}$ is not $O(2^{n})$

Edit: more information:

Since $2^{n+1}$ < $3^{n+1}$ = (n+1) log 3 = O (n log3).

Since $2^{2n}$ < $3^{2n}$ = O (2n log3) = O (n log3).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the fact that there must be some constant. The definition is that $f(x)$ is $O(g(x))$ iff there exists some $c$ such that for sufficient large $x$, $|f(x)|\leq c|g(x)|$.
So, a hint for the first one is $2^{n+1}=2*2^n$,
for the second one you might want to check $x^2$ versus $x$. Does $x^2$ belong to $O(x)$?

Hope it helps.

Comment: I understood your hint for the first one. By the first hint, it would be O$(2^n)$. However, I do not understand why you brought up $x^2$ versus x because I do not see it mirroring the second problem. But to answer your second hint, it would be no. $x^2$ does not belong to O(x).

Comment: $2^{2n}=(2^n)^2$

Comment: Take the log of both sides: $log_{2}(2^{2n}) = log_{2}(2^{n} * 2^{n}) = n^{2}$, while $log_{2}(2^{n}) = n$. Then Phicar's hint for the second one follows.

Comment: It's easier to note that $2^{2n} = 2^{n+n} = 2^n 2^n$.

Answer (score 4):

We know that $f(x) \in \mathcal{O}(g(x))$ if there exist constants $C$, and $k$ so that
$$ |f(x)| \le C |g(x)|$$
whenever $n > k$. I will omit the absolute value as it should be clear that $2^\text{r} \ge 0$.

**(i)** Now,
$$2^{n+1} = 2 \cdot 2^n $$

so we can take $C = 2, k=1$ to see that $2^{n+1} \in \mathcal{O}(2^n).$

**(ii)** Assume that $2^{2n} \in \mathcal{O}(2^n)$. Then, there exists $C$, $k$ so that
$$ 2^{2n} = 2^{n+n} =2^n2^n \le C \cdot 2^n \Rightarrow C \ge 2^n.$$
This is a contradiction as $C$ must be a constant and cannot depend on $n$. Hence, $2^{2n} \not\in \mathcal{O}(2^n).$